# Why Weblogic server is not able to access Oracle DB account on localhost?

Tags: spring, oracle12c, weblogic12c

I have an Spring MVC application with oracle db for storage. I have deployed SpringMVC.war in tomcat and its working fine. But whenever I am deploying my application on Weblogic, it is throwing following exception

[image: Check this image for error]

I have an account with the name "Asif123" on Oracle DB and is configured in "application-context.xml" in my project, but it is only accessible in Tomcat , not Weblogic.

**application-context.xml**

```
<bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:/comp/env/ds1"/>
</bean>
```

Successful datasource test:

[image: successful datasource test]

```
####<30-Oct-2017, 3:27:00,931 PM IST> <Error> <Deployer> <asif-dell> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <727e01e2-9cca-411b-8bc9-290fc833664e-00000014> <1509357420931> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "155312441642365" for task "weblogic.deploy.configChangeTask.1" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'asif123'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'asif123'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at weblogic.jdbc.module.JDBCModule.prepare(JDBCModule.java:411)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.prepare(ModuleStateDriver.java:37)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:77)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:55)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:727)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:239)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:229)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:103)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:241)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:794)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1340)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:235)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:177)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:186)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.prepare(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:42)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.statemachines.targetserver.AwaitingContextUpdateCompletion.callDeploymentReceivers(AwaitingContextUpdateCompletion.java:170)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.statemachines.targetserver.AwaitingContextUpdateCompletion.handleContextUpdateSuccess(AwaitingContextUpdateCompletion.java:66)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.statemachines.targetserver.AwaitingContextUpdateCompletion.contextUpdated(AwaitingContextUpdateCompletion.java:32)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.TargetDeploymentService.notifyContextUpdated(TargetDeploymentService.java:232)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.DeploymentService$1.run(DeploymentService.java:210)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:666)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused By: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'asif123'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1058)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1244)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2396)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2429)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2214)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:797)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please provide the exception as text rather than an image.

Comment: Ok. should i copy paste all the lines from weblogic console?

Comment: Yes, adding in an image is recommended as the link could disappear and also the text isn't searchable.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions (it's a good way to get downvotes, as is txtspk!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you are getting a MySQL error message when connecting to an Oracle database might be a bit of a clue.

Check your Weblogic datasource type - have you incorrectly configured it to be a MySQL connection to an Oracle DB ?

Comment: solved. Actually months ago,while setting up weblogic, i had configured mysql  and oracle datasource which had same account "Asif123" but probably after  that period, i might have changed mysql account password/expired. Just deleted the "mysqlds" and my application is able to access my oracleds. I didn't know that the old  unmanaged datasources can cause problems to current application deployment even though deployed app has nothing to do with it.Thanks for bringing that to my attention.